# How to have multiple toolbars

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I want to have two toolbars on the top but they just stay on each other

```
#The main toolbar 
self.formatbar = QToolBar() 

self.addToolBar( Qt.TopToolBarArea , self.formatbar )
self.formatbar.addSeparator()
self.formatbar.addWidget(self.fontComboBox)
self.formatbar.addWidget(self.fontSizeComboBox)
self.formatbar.addAction(closeActionTB)
self.formatbar.addAction(openActionTB)
self.formatbar.addAction(saveActionTB)
self.formatbar.addAction(capitalActionTB)
self.formatbar.addAction(smallActionTB)
self.formatbar.addAction(colorActionTB)
self.formatbar.addAction(colorActionBGTB)
self.formatbar.addAction(zoomInActionTB)
self.formatbar.addAction(zoomOutActionTB)
self.formatbar.addAction(changeBoldActionTB)
self.formatbar.addAction(changeItalicActionTB)
self.formatbar.addAction(changeFontUnderlineActionTB)
self.formatbar.addAction(undoActionTB)
self.formatbar.addAction(redoActionTB)
self.formatbar.addAction(magnifyTB)
self.formatbar.addAction(demagnifyTB)
self.formatbar.addAction(printActionTB)
self.formatbar.addAction(findActionTB)
self.formatbar.addAction(alLeftTB)
self.formatbar.addAction(alRightTB)
self.formatbar.addAction(alCenterTB)
self.formatbar.addAction(alJustifyTB)
self.formatbar.addAction(bulletListActionTB)
self.formatbar.addAction(numberListActionTB)

#here the toolbar finishes so i want a new toolbar       
self.formatbar2 = QToolBar()
self.insertToolBar(self.formatbar,self.formatbar2)
self.formatbar2.addAction(indentTB) 
self.formatbar2.addAction(deindentTB)
self.formatbar2.addAction(clearTB)
self.formatbar.addAction(copyRightsTB)
```

**The first picture is how to toolbar is right now and the second picture is how I want it to be**

[image: This is how the tool bar is right now]

[image: This is how i want i want it(i put it there manually)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#insertToolBar):

> **void QMainWindow::insertToolBar(QToolBar *before, QToolBar *toolbar)**
>
> Inserts the toolbar into the area occupied by the before toolbar so
>   that it appears before it. For example, in normal left-to-right layout
>   operation, this means that toolbar will appear to the left of the
>   toolbar specified by before in a horizontal toolbar area.

That is to say it places it in the position of `before`, displacing this, and as we observe that is what it accomplishes but it is not what you expect.

You must use [`addToolBarBreak`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#addToolBarBreak):

> **void QMainWindow::addToolBarBreak(Qt::ToolBarArea area =
>   Qt::TopToolBarArea)**
>
> Adds a toolbar break to the given area after all the other objects
>   that are present.

In your case:

```
self.formatbar = QToolBar()
self.addToolBar( Qt.TopToolBarArea , self.formatbar )
# add actions and widgets
self.addToolBarBreak(Qt.TopToolBarArea) # or self.addToolBarBreak()
self.formatbar2 = QToolBar()
self.addToolBar( Qt.TopToolBarArea , self.formatbar2)
# add actions and widgets
```

Comment: yeah it works perefectly but still pyqt hasn't got the greatest of docs :)

Comment: PyQt will always point you to the Qt documentation since PyQt is a Qt wrapper for python. Please if it works please mark it as correct please.